# Visual Studio 2010 regex replace function to array

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio-2010, replace, regex-group

I am looking to replace ([a-zA-Z0-9])/(/) to [$1]
e.g InductionFinal() to [InductionFinal]
in VS 2010 search and replace regex.

regexes `{[a-zA-Z0-9]+}{\(\)}` and `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/(/))` to `[\0]` results in

```
<span data-bind="text: [PatientGender()]"></span>
```

**How do I get rid of ()?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo:

in Visual Studio 2010 to replace   `<span data-bind="text: PatientGender()"></span>` to  `<span data-bind="text: [PatientGender]"></span>`

in search field enter `{[a-zA-Z0-9]+}{\(\)}` and in replace `[\1]`

Answer (score -1):

Use `+`

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\(\)
```

and replace it with :

```
[$1]
```

`+` operator matches one or more of the previous token.

Comment: <span data-bind="text: PatientGender()"></span> gets replaced to <span data-bind="text: [$1]"></span>

Comment: @LIUFA So, you want the () too?

Comment: I want it to disappear as in example <span data-bind="text: PatientGender()"></span> to be <span data-bind="text: [PatientGender]"></span>

Comment: Make sure you check the option of regex in the find option @L

Comment: If option would be unchecked I would find 0 strings like: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\(\) wouldn't I?